# IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension 1

Tags: python, pytorch

I try to solve imbalance multilabel classification, 10 labels and I got the following error:

```
IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension 1
```

when I try to print `sample_probs`, it gives me:

```
tensor([0.8823, 0.9150, 0.3829, 0.9593, 0.3904, 0.6009, 0.2566, 0.7936, 0.9408,0.1332])
```

How to solve it please:

```
import argparse
import random
import copy
    
    
import sys; sys.argv=['']; del sys
    
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Explore pre-trained AlexNet')
'''parser.add_argument('--image_path', type=str, default='your_path', help='Full path to the input image.')
parser.add_argument('--use_pre_trained', type=bool, default=True, help='Load pre-trained weights?')
parser.add_argument("-f", "--file", required=False)'''
parser.add_argument('--seed', type=int, default=42, metavar='S',
                    help='random seed (default: 42)')
args = parser.parse_args()
    
torch.manual_seed(args.seed)
    
kwargs = {'num_workers': 1, 'pin_memory': True} #if use_cuda else {}
    
num_classes = 10
classe_labels = range(num_classes)
sample_probs = torch.rand(num_classes)
#sample_probs = torch.softmax( torch.rand((2, num_classes)), dim=-1)
#print(f'{y_pred=}\n{y_labels=}')
print(sample_probs)
#sample_probs = sample_probs.unsqueeze(0)
#sample_probs.reshape(-1,10)[:,9]
#rint(sample_probs)
    
idx_to_del = [
    i for i, label in enumerate(training_loader.dataset.labels) 
    if random.random() > sample_probs[label]
]
imbalanced_train_dataset = copy.deepcopy(train_dataset)
imbalanced_train_dataset.train_labels = np.delete(training_loader.dataset.labels, idx_to_del, axis=0)
imbalanced_train_dataset.train_data = np.delete(training_loader.dataset.data, idx_to_del, axis=0)
imbalanced_train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    train_dataset, batch_size=8, shuffle=True, **kwargs
)
```

Comment: What are the shapes of sample_probs and training_loader.dataset.labels?

Comment: torch.Size([10])

Comment: Ok, this is for sample_probs what about training_loader.dataset.labels?

Comment: training_loader.dataset.labels.shape is (6077, 10)

Comment: If `sample_probs[label]` works correctly, this will return multiple values, how can you compare multiple values with `random.random()`?

Comment: I want to customize it with my work. I got the orginal code from https://github.com/ufoym/imbalanced-dataset-sampler/blob/master/examples/mnist.ipynb , and they ompare multiple values with random.random().so what i can do please

Comment: I tried to create a tensor with the size (6077,10), it worked well with `sample_probs`, could you please print some of the training_loader.dataset.labels ?

Comment: No, you cannot customize their work directly to your work.

Comment: I tried their code, it worked without problems because they use MNIST dataset and it training_loader.dataset.labels has the size (1,10000) that is why it worked without errors.

Comment: why ? what i can do please

Comment: You should first think of it without coding, how can you solve the problem in multilabel problem. Because I do not want to propose an answer, I need to read what the main purpose of this code in the repository.

Comment: i do multilabel classification using bert in pytorch and it work but i want to solve the imbalance problem so i try to use their code, can i change any thing that make it run correctly

Comment: The problem is that I did not get your error. Thus, I need first to understand where your error locates in the code.

Comment: idx_to_del = [
    i for i, label in enumerate(training_loader.dataset.labels) 
    if random.random() > sample_probs[label]
]

Comment: No, I did get another error not like your error in the dimensionality, I got error because of the comparison between multiple values and random.random()

Comment: is there another way to perform the comp.?

Comment: I can propose `torch.any(random.random() > sample_probs[label])` or torch.all(), instead? you should figure out which one you should use.

Comment: Unfortunately, the same error

Comment: I share it with you, thank you for your help